# ASP.NET / DotNetNuke - Prepend HTML to the body from of a User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, dotnetnuke, google-tag-manager

I was trying to add HTML (specifically the **Google Tag Manager** snippet), right after the opening body tag, from a *ASP.NET user control / DotNetNuke Skin* in code behind.

I tried the following code:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    this.Page.PreLoad += new EventHandler(Page_PreLoad);
}

protected void Page_PreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlGenericControl body = (HtmlGenericControl) Page.FindControl("ctl00$body");
    body.Controls.AddAt(0, new Literal() {ID = "GoogleTagManager", Text = "(...)" };
}
```

This worked so far; the HTML appeared at the desired location. But I noticed that whenever the code was executed, following **PostBacks** seemed not to be processed.

I can't put the HTML into the .aspx page because we have multiple DotNetNuke portals where we don't want to have the same snippet.

Does anyone know a solution how to achieve this, while keeping the postbacks working?

__

Thank you and greetings from Switzerland

Raphael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use the client resource manager placeholders for this.

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/Page/Client-Resource-Management-API

Specifically, in the default.aspx file of your site you'll see a BodySCRIPTS placeholder.

That or if you want, you might be able to target the Body ID element by getting to the Page base, I do something like that for controlling the Title of a page in https://dnnsimplearticle.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#cs/Controls/ArticleView.ascx.cs

```
var tp = (CDefault)Page;
tp.Title = curArticle.Title;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Chris! Client Resources was not an option because the BodySCRIPTS placeholder is placed inside the form.
 
I was able to solve it with:
var tp = (CDefault)Page;
tp.FindControl("Body").Controls.AddAt(0, new Literal() { Text = "<!-- Google Tag Manager -->" });
 
Do you know why PostBacks still work with this solution, while it does not work when adding with the solution I posted in the question?

Answer (score 2):

You can modify **SiteAnalytics.config** file under httpdocs and adapt:

Body
True

This will by applied to the portals who have a Google control under Admin > Google Analytics

But i don't know why, the **postbacks** don't work with this solution.

Do you have a solution for this? **Is the DNN incompatible with GTM**?

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that the Google Tag Manager script can be added after the body tag and this can be found in default.ascx

```
    <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Explicit="True" Inherits="DotNetNuke.Framework.DefaultPage" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" Namespace="DotNetNuke.Common.Controls" Assembly="DotNetNuke" %>
<asp:literal id="skinDocType" runat="server"></asp:literal>
<html<%= HtmlAttributeList %>>
<head id="Head" runat="server">
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
    <meta content="text/javascript" http-equiv="Content-Script-Type"/>
    <meta content="text/css" http-equiv="Content-Style-Type"/>
    <meta id="MetaRefresh" runat="Server" http-equiv="Refresh" name="Refresh" />
    <meta id="MetaDescription" runat="Server" name="DESCRIPTION" />
    <meta id="MetaKeywords" runat="Server" name="KEYWORDS" />
    <meta id="MetaCopyright" runat="Server" name="COPYRIGHT" />
    <meta id="MetaGenerator" runat="Server" name="GENERATOR" />
    <meta id="MetaAuthor" runat="Server" name="AUTHOR" />
    <meta name="RESOURCE-TYPE" content="DOCUMENT" />
    <meta name="DISTRIBUTION" content="GLOBAL" />
    <meta id="MetaRobots" runat="server" name="ROBOTS" />
    <meta name="REVISIT-AFTER" content="1 DAYS" />
    <meta name="RATING" content="GENERAL" />
    <meta http-equiv="PAGE-ENTER" content="RevealTrans(Duration=0,Transition=1)" />

    <link href="StyleSheets/LPStyles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style type="text/css" id="StylePlaceholder" runat="server"></style>
    <asp:placeholder id="CSS" runat="server" />
</head>
<body id="Body" runat="server" >
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=XXX-XXXXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-TK4KKM');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=XXX-XXXXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','XXX-XXXXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

    <dnn:Form id="Form" runat="server" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" >
        <asp:Label ID="SkinError" runat="server" CssClass="NormalRed" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="SkinPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
        <input id="ScrollTop" runat="server" name="ScrollTop" type="hidden" />
        <input id="__dnnVariable" runat="server" name="__dnnVariable" type="hidden" />
    </dnn:Form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As I stated in the question, this does not work if you want to have the code snippet only for one DNN portal. Changes to default.aspx will affect all portals.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to add GTM to a DNN portal. I've Read through a few post about this but haven't been able to come up with a solution. I understand you can add to the default.aspx page but in my case it must be added through a skin package.

I've tried using a cs or VB page but can't get it to add a control to the Body tag.

I can add a attribute to the body tag ok but trying to add a controller always fails.
@rapael you mentioned "var tp = (CDefault)Page; tp.FindControl("Body").Controls.AddAt(0, new Literal() { Text = "" }); "

can you provide some more details as to how you implemented?
Thanks